# Differentiate MMS and SMS via MMS/SMS listeners in Android

Tags: android, sms, mms

Is there any ways to differentiate MMS and SMS messages by using a MMS/SMS listener before they **hit the inbox**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first indicator of an MMS message is a WAP-push with the MIME-type  "application/vnd.wap.mms-message", so you could register a receiver for "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED":

```
    <receiver android:name=".SomeReceiverName"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

To discover whether or not its a received MMS you're going to have to crack open the PDU:s and extract the `X-Mms-Message-Type`, which should be `m-notification-ind` (as per [WAP 209](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wap-209-mmsencapsulation-20020105-a.pdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/affiliates/wap/wap-209-mmsencapsulation-20020105-a.pdf&ei=htWvTsvqGpDDswadxfVz&usg=AFQjCNFrfkpNVXMxZ_ErlgUQBmqNcbROcA&cad=rja)). You can also pick out the X-Mms-Transaction-ID, which one thinks should be stored in the `Telephony.Mms.TRANSACTION_ID` column in the message provider if you want to link them up later.